# Nested Class Constructor Error: No matching Function For Call To OuterClass::InnerClass::InnerClass()

Tags: c++, class, constructor, inner-classes

I have a specific situation where I'm trying to use a nested class and I am passing the outer class to the inner class by reference so that the inner class can use the outer class function.

Here's the idea I am trying to put together:

```
class OuterClass : public parentClass 
{
    public: 
    OuterClass();  
    ~OuterClass() {} 

    void WriteSomething(std::string text); 

     // Inner class here: 
    class InnerClass : public someOtherParent{
         public: 
             InnerClass(OuterClass &obj) : someOtherParent("someText"), _outerObj(obj)
             {
                 // Stuff gets initialized here pertaining to InnerClass
                 // via std::bind() the callBackFunc() gets called below. 
                 
             }

        private: 
             Outerclass &_outerObj; 
             void callBackFunc()
             {
                       _outerObj.WriteSomething("hi"); 
             }
      };

   private: 
   InnerClass _inner;
}
```

In the .cpp file, the OuterClass constructor currently looks like this:

```
OuterClass::OuterClass() : parentClass(100)
{
}
```

In exchange I get an error that says:

```
error: no matching function  for call to 'OuterClass::InnerClass::InnerClass()' 
    3| OuterClass::OuterClass : parentClass(100)
```

I assume that the error is happening because it's trying to look for the default constructor InnerClass() which I don't have since I have an InnerClass constructor that accepts a reference of outer class.

But I am confused as to how to do that in the OuterClass constructor. What do I put inside _inner()?

```
OuterClass::OuterClass : parentClass(100), _inner(??)
{  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if `*this` is valid while you're in a constructor, but that'd be the way to get "a reference to the current object"

Comment: That did the trick! omg. Thank you so much! @NathanPierson